# Eigen - Check if matrix is Positive (Semi-)Definite

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm implementing a spectral clustering algorithm and I have to ensure that a matrix (laplacian) is positive semi-definite.

A check if the matrix is positive definite (PD) is enough, since the "semi-" part can be seen in the eigenvalues. The matrix is pretty big (nxn where n is in the order of some thousands) so eigenanalysis is expensive.

Is there any check in Eigen that gives a bool result in runtime?

Matlab can give a result with the `chol()` method by throwing an exception if a matrix is not PD. Following this idea, Eigen returns a result without complaining for `LLL.llt().matrixL()`, although I was expecting some warning/error. 
Eigen also has the method `isPositive`, but due to a [bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=736) it is unusable for systems with an old Eigen version.

Comment: Cannot you check if it's hermitian first, then look at the eigenvalues? Checking for hermiticity is straightforward.

Comment: You are right about the hermitian part, but ideally I would like to avoid computing eigenvalues for a huge matrix several times, since this is my desired output so I would like this to happen just once if possible.

Comment: Perhaps you can try Cholesky decomposition from Eigen, and that returns `NumericalIssue` if the matrix is negative, see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html

Comment: Probably there is a versioning problem, because: `error: 'class Eigen::LDLT has no member named 'info'`

Comment: Oh actually it works for LLT, although it doesn't for LDLT, thanks for the pointer! If you want you can write an answer so that I accept this, otherwise I will post a snippet as an answer later.

Comment: Glad it helped, I wrote an answer. I'm not sure if it's the best way to go, especially since you are actually interested in the smallest eigenvalue being greater or equal to zero (and hermiticity of course), but it does the job.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a Cholesky decomposition (LLT), which returns `Eigen::NumericalIssue` if the matrix is negative, see the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html).

Example below:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(2, 2);
    A << 1, 0 , 0, -1; // non semi-positive definitie matrix
    std::cout << "The matrix A is" << std::endl << A << std::endl;
    Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> lltOfA(A); // compute the Cholesky decomposition of A
    if(lltOfA.info() == Eigen::NumericalIssue)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Possibly non semi-positive definitie matrix!");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Confusing because that documentation also says "Remember that Cholesky decompositions are not rank-revealing. This LLT decomposition is only stable on positive definite matrices, use LDLT instead for the semidefinite case." I guess it depends on how you define "rank-revealing."

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @vsoftco 's answer, we shall also check for matrix symmetry, since the definition of PD/PSD requires symmetric matrix.

```cpp
Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> A_llt(A);
if (!A.isApprox(A.transpose()) || A_llt.info() == Eigen::NumericalIssue) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Possibly non semi-positive definitie matrix!");
}
```

This check is important, e.g. some Eigen solvers (like [LTDT](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LDLT.html)) requires PSD(or NSD) matrix input. In fact, there exists **non-symmetric and hence non-PSD** matrix `A` that passes the `A_llt.info() != Eigen::NumericalIssue` test. Consider the following example (numbers taken from [Jiuzhang Suanshu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Chapters_on_the_Mathematical_Art), Chapter 8, Problem 1):

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3d A;
Eigen::Vector3d b;
Eigen::Vector3d x;

// A is full rank and all its eigen values >= 0
// However A is not symmetric, thus not PSD
A << 3, 2, 1, 
     2, 3, 1, 
     1, 2, 3;
b << 39, 34, 26;

// This alone doesn't check matrix symmetry, so can't guarantee PSD
Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix3d> A_llt(A);
std::cout << (A_llt.info() == Eigen::NumericalIssue) 
          << std::endl;  // false, no issue detected

// ldlt solver requires PSD, wrong answer
x = A.ldlt().solve(b);
std::cout << x << std::endl;  // Wrong solution [10.625, 1.5, 4.125]
std::cout << b.isApprox(A * x) << std::endl;  // false

// ColPivHouseholderQR doesn't assume PSD, right answer
x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
std::cout << x << std::endl;  // Correct solution [9.25, 4.25, 2.75]
std::cout << b.isApprox(A * x) << std::endl;  // true
```

Notes: to be more exact, one could apply the [definition of PSD](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/semidef/semidef_mat.pdf) by checking `A` is symmetric and all of A's eigenvalues  >= 0. But as mentioned in the question, this could be computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1):

you have to test that the matrix is symmetric (`A.isApprox(A.transpose())`), then create the `LDLT` (and not LLT because LDLT takes care of the case where one of the eigenvalues is 0, ie not strictly positive), then test for numerical issues and positiveness:

```
template <class MatrixT>
bool isPsd(const MatrixT& A) {
  if (!A.isApprox(A.transpose())) {
    return false;
  }
  const auto ldlt = A.template selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().ldlt();
  if (ldlt.info() == Eigen::NumericalIssue || !ldlt.isPositive()) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I tested this on

```
1 2
2 3
```

which has a negative eigenvalue (hence not PSD). Without the `isPositive()` test, `isPsd()` incorrectly returns true here.

and on

```
1 2
2 4
```

which has a null eigenvalue (hence PSD but not PD).